# Why is this query a run away process?

Tags: sql, oracle12c

In Oracle SQL Developer running against 12c, if I run this in a query window, it is fine:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

But if I run from a PROC like this it seems to be a run away process:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE get_stuff_deving(
  param1 IN INT,   -- 1st PI to get Collaborations on
  param2 IN INT, -- 2nd PI to get Collaborations on
  hitlist OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
    query VARCHAR2(32767) := q'[
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
      table_name
    ]';

BEGIN

  debug(query) ;

  OPEN hitlist FOR
  query;

END;
```

I've used this as a starting point before.
I'm not sure what I am doing different this time to cause this problem.

Comment: Define "runaway process".  Are you saying that the call to the procedure does not return?  Or that the procedure returns the cursor and the code fetching from the cursor is taking too long?  Are you measuring the time required to fetch the first row?  Or the last one?  SQL Developer will by default only fetch the first 50 rows and will show data before it is done fetching it.  Your application, on the other hand, might need to fetch the last row before it does something with it.

Comment: It just takes a very long time.  And the processes window pops up. If I right click and select terminate, nothing happens.  Come back after a while and it says "query was not terminated correctly" or something to that affect.  I've never seen the processes window pop up like that before either.

Comment: What is the "it" in the sentence "It just takes a very long time"?  Creating the procedure?  Calling the procedure?  Fetching results from the cursor returned by the procedure?

Comment: "It" means opening the PROC by double clicking it to open in a window and clicking Execute.